# Use asp:calendar as where control for data source

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm trying to set up a simple website to display SQL table content. I wanted to use Calendar control as a source for WHERE statement. I configured calendar declaratively to select current date on control creation. But each time I run the app, this is what I get:

> Operator '==' incompatible with operand types 'DateTime?' and 'Object'

Just so everything is clear, asp WhereParameter for LinqDataSource points to SelectedDate of Calendar control and Calendar has its date parameter set to current date.

So the question is: can I use Calendar control to feed where value to LinqDataSource or other object data source?

Comment: You just need to supply the *current* date/time?

Comment: @user2864740 Nope, I want Calendar to adjust datasource as user makes selection in calendar. This is why I'm wiring data source to control.

Comment: You need to post your markup and relevant code so we can tell what you've tried. Have you considered using a TextBox and then using the [Calendar from the AjaxControlToolkit by Microsoft](http://www.asp.net/AjaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Calendar/Calendar.aspx) or the [jQuery Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)? Both of which appear to the data source as a TextBox.

Comment: @mason - I think you pretty much answered the question. I'll try AJAX tomorrow morning. I hope it will work.